# How to test an object for null in an elegant way in C#?

Tags: c#, null

I want to test if the `Output.ScriptPubKey.Addresses` array is null or not and then assign it to a parameter list. If it's null then I want to set the parameter value to `0`, else use the number of items in the array.

What I've written below feels clumsy and verbose, is there a more elegant way?

```
int addressCount;
if (Output.ScriptPubKey.Addresses == null) { addressCount = 0; } else {
    addressCount = Output.ScriptPubKey.Addresses.Length;
}
var op = new DynamicParameters();
op.Add("@AddressCount", addressCount);
```

The code used to be:

```
op.Add("@AddressCount", Output.ScriptPubKey.Addresses.Length);
```

but sometimes the `Addresses` array is empty.

Comment: `op.Add("@AddressCount", Output.ScriptPubKey.Addresses?.Length ?? 0);`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want the [null-coalescing](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-coalescing-operator) operator combined with the [null conditional](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/null-conditional-operators) operator:

```
int addressCount = Output.ScriptPubKey.Addresses?.Length ?? 0;
```

The left-hand-side of the `??` operator will be used unless the result is null, in which case it will use `0`.  The `?.` evaluates against null and if any part of (a potential chain) evaluates to null, all of it evalutes to null.  Thus it short-circuits and allows you to compose expressions such as this.